# Sumar valores de un array de objetos dependiendo de una propiedad de los objetos

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo un array de objetos:

```
     cuestionario: [
          {
            title: "Enlace civil - Megafonía",
            aplica: false,
            precio: 0,
            uds: 0
          },
          {
            title: "WDS",
            aplica: true,
            precio: 200,
            uds: 3
          },
          {
            title: "SGAE",
            aplica: false,
            precio: 0,
            uds: 0
          },
          {
            title: "Decoración floral",
            aplica: true,
            precio: 1000,
            uds: 1
          },
        ],
```

¿Cómo puedo sumar el precio de todos los objetos que tengan la propiedad `aplica` a `true`?

Lo que he intentado:

```
var acc = 0;
cuestionario.filter(n => n.aplica == true).reduce((acc, v => acc + v.precio));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ojo que tenés mal la sintaxis, falta un `)` al final de `(acc, v` y borrar el último `)`.

```
cuestionario.filter(n => n.aplica == true).reduce((acc, v) => acc += v.precio, 0);
```

La primera vez que iteras el acumulador es 0, habiendo utilizado el inicializador luego de la coma. Al acumulador le sumamos el precio del valor actual en cada iteración.

Comment: ¿Si quisiera multiplicar el precio por las unidades antes de sumarlo cómo lo podría hacer? He intentado `cuestionario.filter(n => n.aplica == true).reduce((ac, v) => (typeof acc === 'object') ? acc += ((acc.precio*acc.uds)+(v.precio * v.uds)) : acc + (v.precio * v.uds));` pero devuelve `1000` en vez de `1600` (con el mismo array que la pregunta)

Comment: `cuestionario.filter(n => n.aplica == true).reduce((acc, v) => acc + v.precio * v.uds, 0);`

Si te fijas más abajo te dan una solución más simple, que es utilizando el inicializador del reduce, siendo 0. Entonces el acumulador en la primera iteracion va a ser 0.

Comment: Si ves que otro usuario dio una mejor respuesta que vos, podes darle un voto positivo en lugar de editar tu respuesta con parte de la suya.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error de sintaxis.

Te falta cerrar el paréntesis después del `v`, quitar el último `)` y el segundo argumento del `reduce` debe ser `0` para indicar que el valor inicial de la variable de acumulación (`acc`) será `0`. Así que esto:

```
cuestionario.filter(n => n.aplica == true).reduce((acc, v => acc + v.precio));
```

Debería ser:

```
cuestionario.filter(n => n.aplica == true).reduce((acc, v) => acc + v.precio, 0);
```

Código:

```js
let cuestionario = [
  {
    title: "Enlace civil - Megafonía",
    aplica: false,
    precio: 0,
    uds: 0
  },
  {
    title: "WDS",
    aplica: true,
    precio: 200,
    uds: 3
  },
  {
    title: "SGAE",
    aplica: false,
    precio: 0,
    uds: 0
  },
  {
    title: "Decoración floral",
    aplica: true,
    precio: 1000,
    uds: 1
  },
];

result = cuestionario.filter(n => n.aplica == true).reduce((acc, v) => acc + v.precio, 0);

console.log(result);
```

[Más información sobre la sintaxis de reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).